# php insert string(a) at multiple positions in string b and concatenate the string

Tags: php, arrays, string, concatenation, substr

I've been working on a solution but my logic isn't quite there yet.

I'm looking to insert string A at multiple positions (positions from an array) into string B.

The array of positions variable is a strpos() return value[].

String B must be concatenated with itself so it contains the original string but with the new string A inserted at in multiple places.

Here's the logic so far:

```
    function add_submenu_back_item( $items, $args ){
        if( 'top-menu' == $args->theme_location ){
                $menu_item_back = '<a class="go-back"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-left-short" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12 8a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H5.707l2.147 2.146a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l3-3a.5.5 0 1 1 .708.708L5.707 7.5H11.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5z"/>
              </svg></a>';
                $subMenuPos = strpos($items, 'sub-menu');
                $new_items = '';
                $arrayPos = strpos_all( $items, 'sub-menu' );
                $offset = 10;
                $values;
                for ($i = 0; $i <= count($arrayPos) - 1; $i++) {
                        // $new_items = substr_replace($items, $menu_item_back, $arrayPos[$i] + $offset, 0);
                        echo substr_replace($items, $menu_item_back, $arrayPos[$i] + $offset, 0);
                }
                
        }
        return ''; // testing mode, should be $new_items but doesnt seem to output the inserted value
} 
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_submenu_back_item', 10, 2 );
```

What I think the logic should express:

- substr() Get the current startPos and endPos to cut out of the string.
- Add the insert value to the end of substr() value.
- if we already have a substr() value then add the new substr() with the insert value to the last one.
- repeat this logic until for loop ends.

I'm trying to insert the $menu_item_back into $menu_items.
$items is a string representing HTML menu navigation.

At the moment it's returning a repeated list $menu_items.

Comment: It would be helpful to have an example of the input and wanted output.

Comment: Be more specific - what exact problem are you experiencing? What exactly do you need help with? The question (although actually you haven't really asked one, if you read it back) is unclear - and as KIKO mentions, without seeing sample input and output data (both expected and actual) it's even harder to understand.

Comment: Thank you, Yes, I have updated my question. Let me know if you need anymore detail or screenshots please.

Comment: Not sure I'm parsing your question correctly, but if part of what you're doing is replacing all occurrences of one substring with another, it would be much simpler (one line) with [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). Then you can manage your concatenations however you need to around that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use JavaScript for this solution. It was easier to access the DOM elements as needed and is a better way to solve this solution since it's Frontend dev and not server-side dev.

Code:

```
// create go-back element button
  var goBackEl = document.createElement('li');
  goBackEl.innerHTML = '<a class="go-back" href="#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="#FFFFFF" class="bi bi-arrow-left-short" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12 8a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H5.707l2.147 2.146a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l3-3a.5.5 0 1 1 .708.708L5.707 7.5H11.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5z"/></svg></a>';

// add go-back button to sub-menu as the first child
  submenuEl.prepend( goBackEl );
```

Comment: A useful answer would always include the code... don't wait for people to ask